# $l^{p}$ and $L^{p}$ applications in PDEs

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, lp-spaces, linear-pde

I am starting to get familiar with PDEs theory.
As far as I know is the purpose is to apply functional analysis methods to study theses complicated problems. and this requires to define certain function spaces in which our unknown "lives".
I understand that these spaces typically defined via integrals, so there's a use of $L^{p}$ spaces of measurable functions for which the {\displaystyle p}p-th power of the absolute value is Lebesgue integrable.

I'm just curious weather there's any application in PDEs theory of $\ell^{p}(I)$ spaces over a general index set $I$ (and $1 \leq p<\infty)$, which defined as follows

$\ell^{p}(I)=\left\{\left(x_{i}\right)_{i \in I} \in \mathbb{K}^{I} ; \sum_{i \in I}\left|x_{i}\right|^{p}<\infty\right\}$

Thank you.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think differential equations on a discrete space are not very interesting.